# Is it possible to use a shared connection for all queries in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

### Background:

I have an application that connects to a sql-server database and loads scripts from several .sql files in a directory.

These queries use temporary tables to communicate their results.

To test the queries I'm using the Management Studio, but this doesn't work since each query tab gets it's own connection.

### The (simplified) question:

I have two queries on separate SQL Query tabs:

```
CREATE TABLE
  #tmp
(
  id INTEGER
)
```

and the second:

```
INSERT INTO 
  #tmp
SELECT
  42
```

Now this doesn't work, because each query tab uses a different connection.

So is it possible to share a connection across different query tabs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure temp tables are unique to the session.  Each tab is a different session.  I don't think you can change that.  Why can't you have them in the same tab?

Comment: This is a simplified version to demonstrate the problem. I have lots of SQL code that I want to split in order to keep a better overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a global temporary table (`##tmp`) to solve your problem?

Comment: That's my current workaround which has the side effect that the table is globally visible. I wondered if there's a better solution.

Comment: Why are you afraid of the table being globally visible while the script runs?

Comment: Because I only *test* the queries in Management Studio. The real end user application also runs the queries and it's possible that different users run it at the same time.